# vTiger CRM 6: Local setup works on /var/www but not on different partition. Why?

Tags: php, apache, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have first `got clone`ed `vtiger` at different partition which is mounted at `/data/`and checked out to 6.5.0

Installed php5.6 and necessary plugins(don't suggest installing php7.x I cannot) from ondrej launchpad.

Created a VHost in `apache2/site-enabled/crm.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "vtiger-local.host.com"
    DocumentRoot "/data/CRM/"
<Directory "/data/CRM/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Edited `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 vtiger-local.host.com
```

After that I did a `chmod -R 777` but It is throwing

```
Call to a member function Execute() on null in /data/CRM/vtigercrm/include/database/PearDatabase.php
```

But same exact configuration is running smoothly when I `git clone` at `/var/www`

Anything I am missing?

P.S Edited `$root_directory` as well as `$site_URL` Forgot to add with the  original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copied the folder and changed the root path and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Open the **config.inc.php** file from the root directory of your CRM. And update the **$site_URL** parameter with the CRM URL and **$root_directory** parameter with the root directory path of CRM.[image]

Comment: as I said I just copied the folder and changed the root path and it started working

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the path in the config.inc.php folder?

Comment: yes did everything.. as I said I just copied the folder and changed the root path and it started working